# Простая WCF- служба и её файл конфигурации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, wcf

Уважаемые коллеги, доброго времени суток!
Есть простая WCF- служба, ниже привожу код её файлов:
Файл IService1.cs

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace EssentialWCF
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService1
  {
    [OperationContract]
    double GetPrice(string ticker);
  }
  public class Service1 : IService1
  {
    public double GetPrice(string ticker)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(ticker) + 94.85;
    }
   }
 }
```

Файл Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace EssentialWCF
{
public class Service
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(
            typeof(Service1),
            new Uri("http://localhost/EssentialWCF"));
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(IService1),
            new BasicHttpBinding(), "");

        serviceHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Для завершения нажмите <ENTER>.\n\n");
        Console.ReadLine();
        serviceHost.Close();
    }
  }
 }
```

Лаборант сказал, изменить службу так, код C# реализации сделал в .config файле помогите пожалуйста............

Comment: А где конфиг? Вы бы как-то более корректней сформулировали вопрос, а то не совсем понятно, что вы хотите

Comment: из кода на c# и контракт перенести в конфиг, чтобы служба хостилась и выполняла контракт из C#